# How to restore full screen video player after PictureInPicture

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios9

I'm using **AVPlayerViewController** with `allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = YES;`,

So when i click on the PictureInPicture button , the `AVPlayerViewController` will be dismissed and the small player will be showed ..

But when I click on the restore button in the small player, it will be closed without showing the **AVPlayerViewController** again ..

So how can I restore the **AVPlayerViewController** after clicking the restore button in the small player ??

My code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>

@interface ViewController ()<AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate>{
    AVPlayerViewController *_AVPlayerViewController;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

    // create a movie player
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://38.96.175.119:1935/aletejahtv/aletejahtv3/playlist.m3u8"];

    _AVPlayerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
    _AVPlayerViewController.delegate = self;
    _AVPlayerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
    _AVPlayerViewController.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = YES;
    _AVPlayerViewController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
    _AVPlayerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    [_AVPlayerViewController.player play];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self presentViewController:_AVPlayerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}


- (void)playerViewControllerWillStartPictureInPicture:(AVPlayerViewController *)playerViewController{
    NSLog(@"playerViewControllerWillStartPictureInPicture");
}

- (void)playerViewControllerDidStartPictureInPicture:(AVPlayerViewController *)playerViewController{
    NSLog(@"playerViewControllerDidStartPictureInPicture");
}

- (void)playerViewController:(AVPlayerViewController *)playerViewController failedToStartPictureInPictureWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"failedToStartPictureInPictureWithError");
}

- (void)playerViewControllerWillStopPictureInPicture:(AVPlayerViewController *)playerViewController{
    NSLog(@"playerViewControllerWillStopPictureInPicture");
}

- (void)playerViewControllerDidStopPictureInPicture:(AVPlayerViewController *)playerViewController{
    NSLog(@"playerViewControllerDidStopPictureInPicture");
}

- (BOOL)playerViewControllerShouldAutomaticallyDismissAtPictureInPictureStart:(AVPlayerViewController *)playerViewController{
    return YES;
}

- (void)playerViewController:(AVPlayerViewController *)playerViewController restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStopWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL restored))completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStopWithCompletionHandler");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using `presentViewController: animated:` in the `playerViewController:restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStopWithCompletionHandler:` in the delegate

So it will represent the **AVPlayerViewController** again after it was dismissed before

My new code:

```
- (void)playerViewController:(AVPlayerViewController *)playerViewController restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStopWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL restored))completionHandler{
    [self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStopWithCompletionHandler");
}
```

Comment: From the docs: "completionHandler For the user interface to be restored, you must implement your method to return a value of YES in this block."

Comment: You can also return false on `playerViewControllerShouldAutomaticallyDismissAtPictureInPictureStart`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to do this with WKWebView/UIWebView? Picture-in-picture comes for free there but there's no AVPlayerViewController to subscribe to, and no picture-in-picture delegate events either.

Comment: Try to ask this as a new question so you may get an answer quicker